# "The system cannot find the path specified" error in anaconda prompt

Tags: python, anaconda, operating-system, command-prompt, environment

While activating the "tensorflow" anaconda environment, I am getting an error that "The system cannot find the path specified and failed to create process". Everything worked perfectly fine yesterday. Now even the base environment is not appearing beside the path. How to solve this problem. [Please find the image here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgPz2.png  and sometimes access denied error is also appearing.